# AS3 ArgumentError #2025

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game as a project for school and have recently encountered a little problem in as3. I'm making a game where you  are maneuvering ship avoiding asteroids, and just added the function so that when you hit an asteroid your ship is removed from the stage via stage.removeChild. Everything is fine until you actually hit something, then this error comes up(and I mean alot, like it keeps repeating itself for as long as the game is on):

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
at Function/com.asgamer.basics1:Engine/private:loop/com.asgamer.basics1:krash()[C:\Users\nti\Desktop\Ship game\com\asgamer\basics1\Engine.as:54]
```

Here's the code(I marked out line 54):

```
 package com.asgamer.basics1
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event; 

    public class Engine extends MovieClip
    {


    private var numStars:int = 80;

    private var enemyList:Array = new Array();

    private var ourShip:Ship;

    public function Engine() : void
    {

        ourShip = new Ship(stage);
        stage.addChild(ourShip);

        ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
        {
            stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), stage.getChildIndex(ourShip));
        }


        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);


    }


    private function loop(e:Event) : void
    {

        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) == 5)
        {

            var enemy:Asteroid = new Asteroid(stage);

            enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);

            enemyList.push(enemy);

            stage.addChild(enemy);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, krash);
            function krash(e:Event):void{
                if (enemy.hitTestObject(ourShip)==true){
                    stage.removeChild(ourShip); <-------------------------- LINE 54

                }
            }

        }
    }


    private function removeEnemy(e:Event)
    {
        enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
    }




}
```

}

Please do remember that I'm sort of a beginner to coding, which would explain other possible "faults" in the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as was mentioned a while ago, is that you don't clean up your `ourShip` after actually removing it from stage. See, once you call `stage.removeChild()` the ship is no longer on stage, but collision check still goes because you didn't remove the enter frame listener. You should add the remove listener statement to the code branch where you remove the ship.

```
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, krash);
        ... // other code
        function krash(e:Event):void{
            for each (var enemy in enemyList)
              if (enemy.hitTestObject(ourShip)==true){
                stage.removeChild(ourShip); 
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, krash); // THIS line
            }
        }
```

EDIT: first, move the `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, krash)` line to the point where you add a `loop` listener, because you don't want to have more than a single one of these, and second, make a complete loop for `hitTestObject` versus `enemyList`. The code above is updated.

Note: Some validity checks may need to be present in the listener code, for example, if `ourShip` is already removed you might just `return` from the event listener function, or skip the hit test checks. This will also help you once you'll start advancing to a single master enter frame listener - it's generally faster having one function as event listener than many for the same event, and also helps you consolidate every bit of code you want to be executed in response for a particular event in one place, instead of searching where did you place that statement that bugs out. This also helps to not fiddle with adding/removing listeners on a regular basis, although sometimes playing with listeners can do you better.

Comment: krash listener is attached to stage. I believe, It should be removed from the stage instead of ourShip.

Comment: @PetrHrehorovsky Right, fixed.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answers! But I tried this, and at first it was working but then after a couple more enemies have passed the stage the error pops up again. Could it be something inside my enemy class that's causing? Cause there is a function in there that removes enemies when they come outside of the stage..

Comment: Ah, didn't noticed that the listener is added multiple times. You should have one listener for your collision handling, not many. Editing.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you so much, but where exactly do mean when you say in the loop listener?

Comment: You have a line `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);` Add the `krash` listener right below this line. Make sure though that in the game reinitialization you add it back after your ship's death.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is caused by the fact that you're trying remove `ourShip` from the `stage` several times. More precisely on each `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event.